# prolog how does a built in predicate get an existence_error?

Tags: prolog, predicate

so I have a prolog assignment that has to be tested with search algorithms provided by the teacher but I keep getting this error:

```
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,op/4),findall/3)
```

which I don't understand because op/4 and findall/3 are built in predicates, right? So how could they not exist?

Anyone has any advice on getting over this? Thanks

Comment: `op/3` is built-in, but not `op/4`. And `findall/3` is reporting.

Comment: @false now I just don't understand why the teacher would put that in their code, but  thanks! I did not know that

Comment: `findall(t,op(_,_,_,_),_).` or similar produces exactly the error you indicated in GNU Prolog. Certainly that was somehow a tiny omission.